# Use the value of a INPUT and refere it to a DIV element AND appendTo() it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to do a simple code (so that I don't have to copy and paste it to multiple buttons) where are any number of buttons where their values are simple as "Home", "Contact", "Register" and stuff like that. So whenever I click that button will make a hidden div to be shown at the DIV (content area) element.

So here is what I mean:

*(hiddenstuff123 id=home) (hidden321stuff id=register) (hid22st id=contact)*

> < Home >< Contact >< Register > **INPUT Buttons**

> DIV Area

Click "Home" button and *hiddenstuff123* will show on the DIV area, you press "Contact" and *hid22st* shows, and so on.

---

So JavaScript will receive a GenericButton click, and will take the BUTTON Value and just Generic Select a div with that id (button value) and appendTo() the "DIV Area".
So I'll show the code I've got already.

```
$('input:button').click(function(){
 var contentName = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
 $(contentName).appendTo('#pageContent');
});
```

The only problem so far is that he isn't selecting the especific hidden div according to the button value.

Thanks and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: What have you done so far? Can we see your code? You can put it to [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) and paste it's link tou your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have assigned `<div id="home">`, `<div id="contact">`, etc, this should work:

```
$('input:button').click(function(){
    var contentName = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $('#' + contentName).appendTo('#pageContent');
})
```

Comment: Ok, this works when the divs are shown, and for some reason when I click it twice the OWN button appends to the contentArea.

Comment: The for example Home button, when I click once the hidden content goes to the div area with no problem, but when I click it again, the home button itself goes to the content area.

Comment: What is the id of the Home button? Is it the same as the id of the div?

Answer (score 0):

considering the following HTML:

```
<button value="contact">CONTACT</button>

<div id="contact"></div>
```

The following jQuery should work:

```
$(':button').click(function(){
   var _id = $(this).val();
    $('#'+_id).appendTo('#pageContent');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

*contentName* is the ID of the DIV to be shown, right? So you should jQuery tell that its an ID by adding a '#' in front of the ID.

```js
$('input:button').click(function(){
 var contentName = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
 $('#'+contentName).appendTo('#pageContent');
});
```